# The problem that javascript cannot be applied depending on whether the URL parameter is

Tags: javascript, html, django

There are a drop down list (select option) to select whether to is_recruiting, a radio option to select 'Total' or 'Period', and input tag of 'from_date' and 'to_date' to set the date when selecting 'Period'.

When the radio option is centered and 'Total' is selected, the date input tag is prevented from being input, and the recruiting option can be selected. Conversely, if the 'Period' is selected, the recruiting option is blocked and the period(from_date & to_date) can be set.

```
<form action="/chart" method="GET">
    <select name="is_recruiting" id="is_recruiting" class="ml-4">
        <option value="A" {% if is_recruiting == "A" %} selected {% endif %}>A</option>
        <option value="B" {% if is_recruiting == "B" %} selected {% endif %}>B</option>
        <option value="ALL" {% if is_recruiting == "ALL" %} selected {% endif %}>ALL</option>
    </select>
    <div class="radio" style="display: inline">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optionRadios" value="total" {% if option_radio != 'period' %} checked {% endif %}/> Total </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio" style="display: inline">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optionRadios" value="period" {% if option_radio == 'period' %} checked {% endif %}/> Period : </label>
        <input autocomplete="off" class="datepicker" name="from_date" id="fromDate" value={{from_date|default_if_none:''}}>
        <label> ~ </label>
        <input autocomplete="off" class="datepicker" name="to_date" id="toDate" value={{to_date|default_if_none:''}}>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs mb-1" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


<script>
    $('input[type=radio][name=optionRadios]').on('click',function () {
    var chkValue = $('input[type=radio][name=optionRadios]:checked').val();
    var recruitingSelect = document.getElementById("is_recruiting");

    if(chkValue == 'total'){
        $( '#fromDate' ).attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
        $( '#toDate' ).attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');

    }
    elif(chkValue == 'total'){
        $( '#fromDate' ).removeAttr('disabled');
        $( '#toDate' ).removeAttr('disabled');
    }

    if(chkValue == 'period'){
        recruitingSelect.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        recruitingSelect.disabled = false;
    }
});
</script>
```

If there are no is_recruiting or optionRadios, from_date, to_date parameters in the url, the above JavaScript code works normally, but if you select an option and submit once and include parameters in the url, the JavaScript is not applied. What's wrong?

http://127.0.0.1:8000/chart/ -> JavaScript applied
http://127.0.0.1:8000/chart/?is_recruiting=A&optionRadios=total -> JavaScript not applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Javascript is most likely breaking because `elif` doesn't exist in JavaScript. Use `else if(...)` instead. Also, you seem to have a typo in the `else if` logic: you are checking for `chkValue == 'total'` for a second time (after the first `if`). I'm guessing the correct conditional would be `chkValue != 'total'`.

Also, since ES6 it is suggested that you use type-safe checking with `===` and `!==`. These operators will check for the datatype of the parameters when comparing both sides of the operation.

Comment: With your answer I was able to get the desired result. How do I write an if statement when there is no parameter, that is, "http://127.0.0.1:8000/chart/"?

Comment: If you want to check if there are no filled inputs in your form, you can do:
`$(form).serializeArray().filter(item => item.value != "").length > 0;`
That'll get the form inputs, transform them into an array, filter this array only by the inputs that have a value, and then test if the length of the array is bigger than zero. You might need to tweak the code a little because of the radio buttons, but that's the general idea.